# Gridview to another activity with imageview

Tags: android, gridview

Will you please please help me solve this problem of mine. I have a gridview with photos on it and i want to do is when i click the photo it will go to the activity 2 and the imageview will appear and a description of the picture below(ofcourse with the use of textview). I try the other codes i saw in this site but it keeps on crashing. here's what the logcat

> 02-14 08:03:30.811 26281-26281/com.posithink.myway W/Bundle: Key Name
>   expected Integer but value was a java.lang.Long.  The default value 1
>   was returned. 02-14 08:03:30.971 26281-26281/com.posithink.myway
>   W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
>                                                                java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Integer
>                                                                    at android.os.Bundle.getInt(Bundle.java:1000)
>                                                                    at android.content.Intent.getIntExtra(Intent.java:4558)
>                                                                    at com.posithink.myway.DriverSignView.onCreate(DriverSignView.java:18)
>                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-14 08:03:30.971
>   26281-26281/com.posithink.myway W/ResourceType: No package identifier
>   when getting value for resource number 0x00000001 02-14 08:03:30.981
>   26281-26281/com.posithink.myway D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   02-14 08:03:30.981 26281-26281/com.posithink.myway W/dalvikvm:
>   threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a1eba8)
>   02-14 08:03:31.561 26281-26281/com.posithink.myway E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        Process: com.posithink.myway, PID: 26281
>                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.posithink.myway/com.posithink.myway.DriverSignView}:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                         Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
>   ID #0x1
>                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
>                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:698)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:175)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:168)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:51)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
>                                                                            at com.posithink.myway.DriverSignView.onCreate(DriverSignView.java:21)
>                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main

(Native Method)

Comment: Post the code from the first Activity (or the Adapter for the GridView) where you call the second Activity. And the code from the second Activity where you _extract_ the data from the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

this is the main

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_signs);

    GridView grid_view = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.GVsign);
    grid_view.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener gvsign = (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (DriverSigns.this, DriverSignView.class);
                intent.putExtra("Name", id);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
        }

    }); grid_view.setOnItemClickListener(gvsign);
}
```

and this is the activity 2

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_sign_view);

    ImageView imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imvSign);

    int imageID = getIntent().getIntExtra("Name", 1);
    imgview.setImageResource(imageID);


}
```